# How to close a docking panel when opening a new instance in the autodesk forge viewer api?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have been displaying data attached to a few nodes in the viewer using a **custom docking panel**. I have attached the listener event on the click of those nodes and instantiating a new docking panel instance.

It works fine. New custom panel get's displayed every time I click on a node. There is a close handler attached to the close button which closes the panel.

But, how can I close the existing panel before opening a new one? I tried to initialize the viewer with initializeCloseHandler so that wherever clicked the opened docking panel closes. But it's not working. I am unable to get the viewer instance there.

Now both instances get added one above another. I am attaching a screenshot of it for reference - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT5Y1.png

How can I achieve this? This is what I have tried so far,

Sample code:

`````
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            #forgeViewer {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: #F0F8FF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
    </body>
   <script>
   var viewer;

    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
        getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
            var token = 'access token here';
            var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
            onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
        }
    };


SimplePanel = function(parentContainer, id, title, content, x, y)
{
  this.content = content;
Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.call(this, parentContainer, id, title,{shadow:false});

// Auto-fit to the content and don't allow resize.  Position at the coordinates given.
//
this.container.style.height = "250px";
this.container.style.width = "450px";
this.container.style.resize = "auto";
this.container.style.left = x + "px";
this.container.style.top = y + "px"; 
this.container.style.zIndex = 2;

};

SimplePanel.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.prototype);
SimplePanel.prototype.constructor = SimplePanel;

SimplePanel.prototype.initialize = function()
{ 
        this.title = this.createTitleBar(this.titleLabel || this.container.id);
this.container.appendChild(this.title);

this.container.appendChild(this.content);
this.initializeMoveHandlers(this.container);

this.closer = document.createElement("span");
this.closer = this.createCloseButton();
this.initializeCloseHandler(this.closer);
this.container.appendChild(this.closer);

var op = {left:false,heightAdjustment:45,marginTop:0};
this.scrollcontainer = this.createScrollContainer(op);
// console.log("id - "+viewer.model.getFragmentList().fragments.fragId2dbId);
console.log(viewer.getSelection());
var id = viewer.getSelection();
var dataItem;
var data = [
    {
        id:"2648",
        name:"Chiller",
        temp:"300 deg",
        serviceReq:true,
        reservations:"3"
    },
    {
        id:"2228",
        name:"Door",
        temp:"150 deg",
        serviceReq:false,
        reservations:"4"
    },
    {
        id:"2198",
        name:"Cooler",
        temp:"400 deg",
        serviceReq:true,
        reservations:"2"
    }
]

data.forEach(item => {
    if(item.id == id){
        dataItem = item;
    }
})

var html = [
    '<div class="uicomponent-panel-controls-container">',
    '<div class="panel panel-default">',
    '<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id = "clashresultstable">',
    '<thead>',
    '<th>Key</th><th>Value</th>',
    '</thead>',
    '<tbody>',
    '<tr><td>ID</td><td>'+dataItem.id+'</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Name</td><td>'+dataItem.name+'</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Temperature</td><td>'+dataItem.temp+'</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Service Requests</td><td>'+dataItem.serviceReq+'</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>Reservations</td><td>'+dataItem.reservations+'</td></tr>',
    '</tbody>',
    '</table>',
    '</div>',
    '</div>'
].join('\n');


$(this.scrollContainer).append(html);

this.initializeMoveHandlers(this.title);    
};



    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {

    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
    var startedCode = viewer.start();
    if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
    }

    console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

});

var documentId = 'urn:(urn)';
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);


function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
    var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
    viewer.addEventListener( Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event=>{

        var content = document.createElement('div');
        var mypanel = new  SimplePanel(NOP_VIEWER.container,'mypanel','My Panel',content,20,20);
        mypanel.setVisible(true);
})
}

// function closer(){     -- tried to attach this handler to the viewer instance,but didn't work
//     SimplePanel.setVisible(false);
// }

function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
    console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
}


   </script>
</html>````


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT5Y1.png
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to use a viewer extension to manage your panel in order to reuse the same panel instance. Here are some examples for you:

- https://github.com/yiskang/forge-au-sample/blob/master/properties/scripts/AdnPropsPanel.js
- https://github.com/yiskang/forge-au-sample/blob/master/model-structure/scripts/AdnStructurePanel.js

If you don't want to implement an extension, you may store the `mypanel` variable somewhere, and use `if` statement to destroy the old panel before creating a new one.

```
var mypanel = null;

// Other code snippet

viewer.addEventListener( Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event=> {
        if( mypanel != null ) {
           //NOP_VIEWER.container.removeChild( mypanel.container );
           mypanel.uninitialize();
           mypanel = null;
        }

        var content = document.createElement('div');
        mypanel = new  SimplePanel(NOP_VIEWER.container,'mypanel','My Panel',content,20,20);
        mypanel.setVisible( true );

})
```

Hope it helps!