# Is it possible to prevent reloading when the DockingPanel panel is displayed?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

## DockingPanel specifications

I'm not good at English, so I'm sorry if there are unpleasant expressions.

Currently, we are using Autodesk Platform Service to create viewers and dashboards.

The screen of the external site is embedded using iframe in the custom panel inherited from DockingPanel.

There is currently a problem with this, and the loading of the external site itself is going well, but when you move the panel itself or hide and show the panel from the Toolbar once, the loading of the external site runs again. It's happening that it's going to be.

As a DockingPanel specification, I understand that the entire panel element is re-added to the DOM each time it is displayed, but is that correct?
Also, instead of adding this movement to the DOM, is it possible to add hide to the attribute or change it to something like display: none?

It is created based on the following git.

https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo

I'm still not sure how DockingPanel can change properties, and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait.  If I understand correctly, you embedded a website in Docking panel. You want to show hide the panel without reloading the website? I am afraid this is a general question of iFrame and DOM, instead of APS viewer specific. If you could provide a sample video to show what the question exactly is, that would help us to share possible comments if it is APS related.

Comment: or, you may just wanted to know how to hide and show docking panel? the other post might be a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408945/how-to-close-a-docking-panel-when-opening-a-new-instance-in-the-autodesk-forge-v .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr.Liang.I'm a developer using Autodesk Platform Services with the questioner.
We assume that regardless of what is embedded within the panel, the code in the following path may be the culprit.
・In LMV/src/gui/DockingPanel.js

The DockingPanel.prototype.bringToFront function in the image is called when the panel is moved, and the panel is rebuilt when the appendchild on line 776 is executed.

[image: ~/DockingPanel.js]

Therefore, I think it would be a solution if the setVisible function described after line 170 of this code is called with true when the panel is moved, and if there is a mechanism so that the bringToFront function is not called when the panel is displayed.
What do you think?

Comment: Thank you for the investigation. Sorry I have no quick answer or experience with this. I am asking engineer team. Will get back to you once getting any comment

Comment: As you mentioned, DockingPanel.prototype.bringToFront() is invoked when moving, actually clicking titie bar of panel,  a panel. This is because to move up the panel at top-most in z-order than othre panels. Otherwise the panel would be moving at  behind of other panels. On the othre hands, moving position of iframe in DOM node causes reloading of web page contents of iframe. This is an old but not resolved issue of web browser, seemigly bug of browser. There are multiple similer queries on stackoverflow but no resolution and workaround yet.